# website rendering windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7

Is anyone noticing any websites being rendered differently on windows 7. I don't beleieve this is a browser it. example:

i have a site with drop down menu. on my computer running windows 7 the dropdowns are correct in IE8 but misaligned in IE7. I looked at the site on a co-workers computer and the dropdowns looked correct in IE7 but misaligned the other way on IE8.

I also think i have noticed differences with fonts. In ALL of my browsers the font is bold, but in co-workers computer the font is not bold.

Any insight would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which font are you using? Do the fonts exist in both PCs? If you check *Developer Tools* in IE8, do the fonts actually show as bold in the CSS, or do they only appear as bold in your PC?

Also, are the two browsers in strict mode, or quirks mode? Try running IE8 in compatibility mode, and check if it matches IE7.

Comment: hmm here goes. 
windows is set to use segoe
yes the fonts exist on both
in developer tools (and firebug) on my pc they do show as bold, but in co-workers they do not.
I messed around with all the different ie modes, but the alignment is off. oh side note i have ie9 on my machine but co-worker has ie8 if that helps.

Comment: Yup, the browser versions do make a difference in style discrepancies. What you'd need to do is post an extract of the HTML making up your drop-down menus and the CSS for it. If Firebug is showing it as Bold in one pc/browser and not bold in the other, it is almost definitely being styled by different selectors.

Comment: hmmm. the menu codes, is an old one consisting of html, css, and javascript, so its a lot of code. I guess my thinking is that its more of a windows 7 issues since ALL my browsers (chrome, opera, safari, IE, and FF) all display the font as bold. is that thought process logical?

Comment: No, it's more like you have very recent (if not the latest) versions of all of those browsers in Windows 7, so they're behaving in a more standards compliant manner. On the other hand ie8 is behaving as per some quirk. The actual version of Windows doesn't have any direct bearing on how content is rendered in the browser.

Comment: What you want to do is check in Firebug/IE9 dev tools, which selector is styling your dropdown fonts. And do the same in IE8 in the other computer. You can change those about to get the desired result.